# how to restore h2 database in java

Tags: java, database, javafx, h2, restore

How to restore a backup of h2 database in java. I store the backup on

```
statement.execute(String.format("SCRIPT TO '%s'","path.sql"));
```

but I don't know how to restore this backup I tried

```
statement.execute(String.format("RUNSCRIPT FROM '%s'", "path.sql"));
```

but it gives me an error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Sequence "SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_072EDF24_6F60_47A3_A01C_3013DBBD9743" already exists; SQL statement:           
CREATE SEQUENCE PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_072EDF24_6F60_47A3_A01C_3013DBBD9743 START WITH 10 BELONGS_TO_TABLE [90035-197]
```

Comment: I solved it by my self.what i need is to delete current database before restoring another

Comment: this is related to javafx in that .. ?